# Understanding indentation in Python

Tags: python, indentation

I'm starting out on Python at school, and as homework, we have to make a hangman game. My only problem is it always seems to try and indent everything, and even when I do, it still wants an indentation.

Heres my code:

```
import random
global guess

def checkGuess():
    turns = 5
    n = 0
    guess = input('Please guess a letter:')
    guesslen = len(guess)
    while len(guess) > n:
        if guesslen >1:
            print ('Please only guess a single letter.')
            checkGuess()
        elif guess in secretWord:
            print (guess)
            n = n+1
            checkGuess()
        elif guess not in secret:
            turns -= 1
            print ('Nope.')
            print (turns), 'more turns'
            if turns < 5: print ('        OMMMMMD')
            if turns < 5: print ('       MMMMMMMMM')
            if turns < 5: print ('      =MMMMMMMMM?')
            if turns < 5: print ('      ,MMMMMMMMM:')
            if turns < 5: print ('       MMMMMMMMM')
            if turns < 5: print ('        .MMMMM,')
            if turns < 5: print ('                       ')
            if turns < 3: print ('  ZMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM7L')
            if turns < 3: print (' MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMMIMMMMMMMMMMMMMIMMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print ('MMMM DMMMMMMMMMMMM MMMM')
            if turns < 3: print (' ZD  DMMMMM?MMMMMM  DO')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 2: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 1: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 1: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 1: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 1: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 1: print ('     DMMMMM MMMMMM')
            if turns < 1: print ('      MMMM+ ?MMMM')
            if turns == 0:
            print ('The answer is'), (secretWord)

print('H A N G M A N')
secretWord = random.choice (['crocodile','elephant','penguin','pelican', 'leopard', 'hamster', 'lion',])
i = ('')
g = len(secretWord) <--- THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
length = 0
print (secretWord)
while g > length:
    i = i + (' _')
    length = length + 1
print(i)
guess = ('')
checkGuess()
```

I've tried every method already suggested on this website and others. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a traceback? The code as pasted has incorrect indentation for the 'the answer is' line.

Comment: "...it always trys to indent..." . What is "it"? Are you using an IDE? Maybe you are using IDLE?

Comment: indent `print ('The answer is'), (secretWord)` or write it on the same line like other lines above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the problem is on line 57. You have an `if` statement, but you haven't indented its contents.

```
        if turns == 0:
        print ('The answer is'), (secretWord)
```

Should be

```
        if turns == 0:
            print ('The answer is'), (secretWord)
```

Comment: There are some other issues in the above code. I recommend you use a lint tool like [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) to help you find them.

Comment: This appears to be the problem to me as well. Also you don't appear to define 'secret' used on line 17.

Comment: @fulhack actual i do as what your refering to is a function and is skipped out untill i declare 'secret' later. And it's ment to be 'secretWord'

Comment: @DavidDixon You say `secret`, but I think you mean `secretWord`.

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

1. You don't keep track of the guesses
2. Use globals for the turn and the guesses, the turn and guesses vars shall be outside your function
3. while(guess)> n should be if(guess) > n
4. use raw_input instead of input
5. Add a guesses.append(guess) to the winning cycle
6. Check if the guesses generate the word:

   if sorted(list(secretWord))==sorted(list(guesses)):
7. You messed up all your variable names, secret - secretWord..
8. Add indentation after

   if turns == 0:
9. if turns == 0: ... add an else block like this "else: checkGuess()"

Comment: I hope you're also on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: the input bits fine raw_input was changed to input in a recent update

Comment: @kojiro ahah yes, but mainly as an asker there ;)